# How to read in php file upload from mysql current record the id?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I read in the following code from the current record from the current database `sob` from the table `articles` the data field `id` and write it to `$current_id` ?

Generally said, I want to change the file name for the uploaded files, always  first the "ID2" (This ID2 does not change for the current actions) and then the filename.

The code below give me only `000000`for the $new_id

I am since one week blocked and have no idea. I tried so many thing. I read so much.  And I learned a lot, but I did not get the result. It is frustrating ...

This is the html code in "body_articles.php"

```
            <?php session_start();

                $_db_host = "localhost";
                $_db_username = "admin0";
                $_db_passwort = "dfgfghxyxc";
                $_db_datenbank = "sob";

                # Verbindung zur Datenbank herstellen
                $_link = mysql_connect($_db_host, $_db_username, $_db_passwort);

                # Pr�fen ob die Verbindung geklappt hat
                if (!$_link)
                {
                    # Nein, also das ganze Skript abbrechen !
                    die("Keine Verbindung zur Datenbank m�glich: " .
                        mysql_error());
                }

                # Datenbank ausw�hlen
                mysql_select_db($_db_datenbank, $_link);

            ?>

            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">

            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8" />

                <title>SoB - Administration</title>

                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">


                <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/multiupload.js"></script>

                <script type="text/javascript">

                    var config =
                    {
                        support : "image/jpg,image/png,image/bmp,image/jpeg,image/gif",     // Valid file formats
                        form: "demoFiler",                  // Form ID
                        dragArea: "dragAndDropFiles",       // Upload Area ID
                        uploadUrl: "upload.php"             // Server side upload url
                    }

                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        initMultiUploader(config);
                    });


                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        var storedFiles = [];
                        $('#myfiles').on('change', function() {
                            $('#messages').html('');
                            var myfiles = document.getElementById('myfiles');
                            var files = myfiles.files;
                            var i=0;
                            alert("files uploading");
                            for (i = 0; i<files.length; i++) {
                                var readImg = new FileReader();
                                var file=files[i];
                                if(file.type.match('image.*')){
                                    storedFiles.push(file);
                                    readImg.onload = (function(file) {
                                        return function(e) {
                                            $('#uploadedfiles').append('<tr class="imageinfo"><td><img width="80" height="70" src="'+e.target.result+'"/></td><td>'+file.name+'</td><td>'+Math.round((file.size/1024))+'KB</td><td><a href="" class="lnkcancelimage" file="'+file.name+'" title="Cancel"><img src="delete.png" width=34" height="34"/></a></td></tr>');
                                        };
                                    })(file);
                                    readImg.readAsDataURL(file);
                                }else{
                                    alert('the file '+file.name+' is not an image<br/>');
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        $('#uploadedfiles').on('click','a.lnkcancelimage',function(){
                            $(this).parent().parent().html('');
                            var file=$(this).attr('file');
                            var strID = myTrim(document.demoFiler.ID2.value);
                            for(var i=0;i<storedFiles.length;i++) {
                                if(storedFiles[i].name == file) {
                                    storedFiles.splice(i,1);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            return false;
                        });

                        $('#lnkupload').click(function(){
                            var data = new FormData();
                            var i=0;
                            for(i=0; i<storedFiles.length; i++) {
                                data.append('files'+i,storedFiles[i]);
                            }

                            if(i>0){
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: 'load.php',
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    contentType: false,
                                    data: data,
                                    processData: false,
                                    cache: false
                                }).done(function(msg) {
                                        storedFiles = [];
                                        if(msg){
                                            alert(msg);
                                        }else{
                                            $('#messages').html('Images uploaded successfully');
                                        }
                                    }).fail(function() {
                                        alert('error');
                                    });
                            }
                            return false;
                        });

                    });

                  function jsShowArticle() {
                      js_articles = JSON.parse(json_string);
                      $('[name="recordCurrent"]').attr("id",js_articles[0]);
                      document.demoFiler.ID2.value = js_articles[0];
                  }

                </SCRIPT>

                <style type="text/css">.buttonarea: (\a)</style>

            </head>

            <body class="page page-id-11505 page-template-default" onload="jsShowArticle();">

            <div id="page-wrap">

            <?php
            include('includes/header.html');
            ?>

            <div id="container-main">
                <div id="main-content">

                    <div class="post" id="post-11505">

                        <title>SoB - Administration</title>

                        <div class="entry">

                            <div id="dragAndDropFiles" class="uploadArea">
                            <br>
                            <span style="padding-left: 20px">To upload more pictures for this item click Browse</span>
                            <br>
                            <span style="padding-left: 20px">The order of the upload decide the order to show the pictures</span>

                            </div>

                            <form name="demoFiler" id="demoFiler" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="">
                                <input id="ID2" type="text" name="ID2name">
                                <input type="file" name="multiUpload" id="multiUpload" multiple />
                                <input type="submit" name="submitHandler" id="submitHandler" value="Upload" class="buttonUpload" />

                            </form>

                            <div class="progressBar">
                                <div class="status"></div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div id="aside">

                </div>

                <br class="clearfloat" />
            </div> <!-- End of main container -->

            </div><!-- END Page Wrap -->

            <div id="footer">
                <br class="clearfloat" />

                <?php
                if(isset ($_SESSION['name']))
                {
                    $loginTitle="Logout";
                    $loginLink="body_logout.php";
                }
                else
                {
                    $loginTitle="Login";
                    $loginLink="body_login.php";
                }
                ?>

            </div>

            </body>

            </html>
```

File upload.php

```
            <?php
            $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'admin0', 'fdhfuirkfk');
            if (!$link) {
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
            }

            $db_selected = mysql_select_db('sob', $link);
            if (!$db_selected) {
                die('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
            }

            $current_id = (int)$_REQUEST['currentRecord']; // here is Your current_id

            // if You're just getting data so You echo result from db
            if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET"){
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id > " . $current_id . " ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1");
                $result = mysql_fetch_row($result);
                echo json_encode($result);
                exit(0);
            }

            // and there You're pushing file and echo $_POST['index']
            if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
                $new_id = sprintf( "%06d", $current_id);
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "sobimages/" . $new_id . $_FILES['file']['name'])){
                    echo($_POST['index']);
                }
                exit(0);
            }?>
```

How can I get the value from the form field `ID2` read this value into `$new_id` into the `upload.php` file without interfering the other actions?

- -   +

The  last file is `nextarticle.php` as example. It have nothing to do with the multi fileupload, I just post is to give more information. It read the next record.

```
<?php
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'admin0', 'fdhfuirkfk');
    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db('sob', $link);
    if (!$db_selected) {
        die('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $current_id = $_REQUEST['currentRecord'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id > " . $current_id . " ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1");
    $result = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Comment: Hello kupendra.  Thank you for your support.  I added more code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$link = mysql_connect('parsley.arvixe.com:3306', 'admin0', 'fdhfuirkfk');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('sob', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}

$current_id = (int)$_REQUEST['currentRecord']; // here is Your current_id

// if You're just getting data so You echo result from db
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET"){
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id > " . $current_id . " ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1");
    $result = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    echo json_encode($result);
    exit(0);
}

// and there You're pushing file and echo $_POST['index']
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    $new_id = sprintf( "%06d", $current_id);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "sobimages/" . $new_id . $_FILES['file']['name'])){
        echo($_POST['index']);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: It does not work.
I am so upset about myself!

I am really so dumb? I try everything, since 7 days I sit only on this problem. 

I slowly  give up. I should not write programs, better to work in Burgerking.

I have no idea why this is not working. I add now really all the code.  I hope that you really  amazing programmers find the solution.  I am so frustrated ...

I am sorry to tell me feelings ...

Comment: My friend don't be sad. I was also like You in my past. So if You see that cannot do this way, so write your code another way. Try to decouple Your code to various files and functions and call them. I believe You can achieve result.

Comment: Hi anarjafarov, I do not use skype.
I  use line.
Why is it not possible to give a idea here?

Nice greetings and thank you to you for cheering my up

Comment: 1.create separate functions with needed input arguments and return result. 2. mysql_* is deprecated use PDO or mysqli_*